# c# Localization with button click that affects all the forms at once

Tags: c#, localization, culture, buttonclick, winapp

I have made a kiosk application in c# first form has 6 languages (default is english) when i press the spanish button it changes language on the next form but the other forms stay the same

```
private void btn_esp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");           
        ChangeLanguage("es-ES");
        this.Hide();
        f1.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
        f1.DesktopLocation = new Point(100, 100);


    }

public void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1a));


            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));

            foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources_child = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1a));
                resources_child.ApplyResources(child, child.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            }

        }
    }
```

i am using changeLanguage function in every other form but it does not work